# CakePHP 3 - How to apply validation conditionally?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Trying to restrict a compareWith to just on create

```
$validator->add('password', [
'compare' => [
'rule' => ['compareWith', 'password_confirmation']]]);
```

I cant seem to work out how to do it added 'create' to the end like

```
$validator->add('password', [
'compare' => [
'rule' => ['compareWith', 'password_confirmation']]],'create');
```

in fact i have tried the 'create' in many places either build errors or still validating on an edit

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$validator->add("password", "compare", [
    "rule"    =>  ["compareWith", "password_confirmation"],
    "message" =>  __("Password and password confirmation fields don't match."),
    "on"      =>  "create"
 ]);
```

This will certainly work.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD